# Can I determine if a thread has a QEventLoop?

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a Windows DLL that may run under a QApplication, or may run under a regular Win32 application. I want to use the Qt Networking classes which require an event loop.

If running in a regular Win32 (non-Qt) app, I have to start a QThread or QEventLoop for the Qt networking signals and slots to work. *Note: the DLL uses QtWinMigrate.*
But if running in a QApplication, there will already be an event loop, and no need to start a new QThread.

Is there a way to check for an existing QEventLoop?

*Clarification*
The DLL runs under a large legacy code base, and the thread where my class is running may or may not be a QThread.

Comment: Your really should force the users of the DLL to start a thread, if needed...

Comment: Can't you check if `QApplication::instance` exists?

Comment: It seems like all `QThread`s have an event loop, so the big question here is whether it is running or not. Maybe `isRunning()`?

Comment: I just made a clarification to the question. QApplication::instance exists since we're using QtWinMigrate. But my class may be running in a non-QThread worker thread and not have an event loop. Is this making sense? Sorry, I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. Maybe it doesn't matter and I should just always start a new QThread?

Comment: There is a function: `bool QEventLoop::isRunning() const`, that _returns true if the event loop is running; otherwise returns false. The event loop is considered running from the time when exec() is called until exit() is called._ The problem is, can you access the event loop?

Comment: May I ask you a stupid question: if there is a case anyway in which you must create and run `QThread`, why bother detecting if your code is currently run in a `QThread` or in another (non-Qt) event loop? If you can create a `QThread`, create it regardless of type of the event loop currently running.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov I'm coming to the same conclusion, I'll just always create a new QThread. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering for Qt 5.

You can get current `QThread` by calling static function [`QThread::CurrentThread`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#currentThread). Practice has shown to me that it returns non-null pointer even if there is no `QApplication` instance in your program.

The next thing to do is calling [`QThread::eventDispatcher`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#eventDispatcher)
 function. It returns `NULL` if there is no Qt event loop in the current thread. Unfortunately, this function is available only since Qt 5. Hope there are some other ways to get the desired information in earlier versions.

By the way, I'd recommend you to start `QThread` regardless of whether your code runs in a Qt or any other event loop. If there is a case when you need to spawn `QThread` anyway, I'd prefer to spawn it always. Less code, less bugs.

UPDATE: In Qt 4 you can use:

```
QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()
```

See [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstracteventdispatcher.html#instance).

Comment: This answers the question. And as I'm stuck with Qt 4.7 for now, I'll take your advice and always create the QThread.

Comment: @matthewmyers Updated for Qt4 anyway. You can experiment with it.

Comment: I wonder if either is thread safe to wait on (e.g. to wait certain thread to enter event loop)

Comment: Qt 5.15.2, created a `QThread` without an event loop (by overriding `run`; also the call stack confirms there's no event loop when I put a breakpoint there) -- but `eventDispatcher()` still returns a non-null pointer to some `QEventDispatcherWin32` instance :(

Answer (score 2):

```
int QThread::loopLevel() const
```

Returns the current event loop level for the thread.
Note: This can only be called within the thread itself, i.e. when it is the current thread.
This function was introduced in Qt 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

From [QThread docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details):

> A QThread object manages one thread of control within the program.
>   QThreads begin executing in run(). **By default, run() starts the event
>   loop by calling exec() and runs a Qt event loop inside the thread.**

So, when you call `run`, it has an event loop.

Comment: He is asking about thread, as far as I understood. Not about the application.

Comment: This is not right either. You can run without an event loop.

Comment: @ddriver If he uses a `QThread`, according to the docs, there will already be a running event loop when the thread starts. So, there's no need to check.

Comment: @Michael - you can overload `QThread` and implement run without calling exec at the end - and you will have a thread instance that is running without a running event loop.

Comment: The docs states that _By default, run() starts the event loop by calling `exec()` and runs a Qt event loop inside the thread_, so when you call `run()` it should call `exec()`. This doc, however, doesn't seem very correct in my opinion. From here it seems `run()` calls `exec()`, but I think YOU should manually call `exec()`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I know QThread starts an event loop, at the point my class is running, it may be in a non-QThread and I have to start one to get an event loop.

Comment: By default does not mean always, there are many use cases where you need a thread but you don't need the event loop. It is perfectly legal use. If you overload `QThread` you implement run, and you only start the event loop if you need it.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the doc seems tricky to me. At first glance, it seems `run()` automatically calls `exec()`.

Comment: @Michael - yes, the default implementation of `QThread` calls exec - it actually doesn't do anything but that, so you have to use queued async connections to drive things through the event loop. But if your usage case doesn't require all this you can simply get the job done in `run` and exit.